# How to get list of all mongo databases in javascript while using any other database?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm trying to list all the databases while working inside some 'abc' database using javascript.
my admin username is 'xyz' and password is 'abc'.
But it is displaying an error-
error: uncaughtException: Mongo is not defined.
can anyone guide me for the same?
thanx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the problem was with authentication of db.
The mongo I'm using requires admin authentication before querying or trying any command to process data.
I inserted code to authenticate db and got access to db.admin() function of mongodb.

By the way thanx to @arcyqwerty and @Amadan for your support.

Answer (score 4):

From the console you can simply run `show dbs`

If you need the output in a Javascript object, try `db.adminCommand('listDatabases')`

Comment: its responding as-error: uncaughtException: Object #<Db> has no method 'adminCommand'

Comment: What version of mongo are you using? (check using `mongo --version`)

Comment: Also make sure you have not overwritten the db variable

Comment: I'm using version 2.4.5.

Comment: Are you using the `mongo` command directly for the db console?  The exact command may be different if you are using a language driver.  When I enter an undefined method into mongo it gives me `TypeError: Property 'asdfjklj' of object test is not a function` so I'm not sure how to reproduce your issue

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB is a serverside technology. JavaScript (unless you're using Node.js, in which case you should have tagged it) is a client-side technology. Might as well shout for someone in Japan to cook you dinner - too far. You would need to ask a server-side component to ask MongoDB for you and pass you the results.